# Not able to run second instance of XAMPP on Windows due to blocked port

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I am trying to run two instances of XAMPP on Windows 10. Each instance has different version of PHP. I installed second XAMPP next to the first one, changed ports from 80 to 8080 and 443 to 444 and ran it. When I ran it for the first time, there was no problem, it ran good. But when I changed vhosts and restarted Apache server few times, it happend that I cannot run it again. Always I get this error message:

```
14:40:31  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
14:40:31  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
14:40:31  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:40:31  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:40:31  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:40:31  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
14:40:31  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Skype is not running, all ports checked with netstat and no application is using ports 8080 or 444. First instance of XAMPP on porst 80 and 443 is running correctly. And it doesn't matter if I run it together or separately.

Do you have any idea how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Have you skype on your system?

Comment: Yes, but what I know, it is not running. There is just some Microsoft Skype Preview task running. But how I wrote above, first instance of XAMPP and Apache on ports 80 and 443 is running good. I have problems just with second instance

Answer (score 0):

Did you use netstat -a? That prints all the allocated listening ports as well as the ones that are currently established. Possibly one or both of 444 or 8080 fall into that category.